# Access to alias parameters within awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'd like to define a bash alias for obtaining the status of a systemctl service.
This is what I have done so far:

```
status () { systemctl list-units -a | grep $1 | awk '{print $4}'; }
```

which prints me out the status of the systemctl service.
Now I want to also print the name of the systemctl service, i.e., the parameter I have passed to status(). I can't just write

```
awk '{print $1 " " $4}'
```

because `$1` would refer to the first parameter caught by awk.
So how can I access to the "original" `$1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the parameters as command line parameters:

```
... | awk -v service="$1" '{print service " " $4}'
```

Also suggested by @ctac_ you can eliminate the `grep` command:

```
awk -v 'service="$1" '$1==service{print $1,$4}'
```

Comment: Small improvement: `... | awk -v service="$1" '{print service,$4}'`

Comment: and no need of grep : awk -v 'service="$1" '$1==service{print $1,$4}'